# Grafana bar graph sorting, lower values not visible

Tags: grafana

I have a bar graph in Grafana (with InfluxDb). Its grouped by time and a tag. But I noticed that the large values are being drawn over the lower values.

Example below. You can see the points where the lower value bars are. I would expect that the lower values are drawn on top. Is this a setting?

[image]

Query:
[image]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your grafana query ?

Comment: @MarkB Added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your data it appears to be showing the time spent in each component of a request pipeline, so my suggestion would be to present them as stacked bars, which will better represent how each contributes to the total time spent.

You can enable stacked mode on the Display tab of the graph edit panel.

If you're more interested in seeing how each item compares to the others, then maybe a line or point plot would be easier to read, especially as superimposed bars will be be assumed to be stacked by most viewers.

Comment: Yes, that is the workaround im using atm. It works, but its confusing for some people :) Guess Ill have to stick with it.